# How do I map a service containing a static webpage under a subpath using ambassador in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, ambassador

How do I map  a service containing a static webpage  under a subpath using ambassador in kubernetes ?

this is my yaml file

```yaml
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v2
kind:  Mapping
metadata:
  name:  grafana
spec:
  prefix: /grafana/
  method: GET
  service: monitoring-grafana.default:80
  timeout_ms: 40000
```

**
and this is the response i get when trying to navigate

If you're seeing this Grafana has failed to load its application files

1. This could be caused by your reverse proxy settings.
2. If you host grafana under subpath make sure your grafana.ini root_url setting includes subpath
3. If you have a local dev build make sure you build frontend using: yarn start, yarn start:hot, or yarn build
4. Sometimes restarting grafana-server can help
   **

Answer (score 3):

Have you read through the Monitoring page on the Ambassador Docs?  There's a bit about implementing Prometheus + Grafana if that helps: https://www.getambassador.io/docs/latest/howtos/prometheus/